# Why @PostFilter don't work sometimes in Spring Security service?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I'm using spring security in my project. I have a service as follow:

```
public interface A {

   @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")
   List<MyEntity> method1();

   @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")
   List<MyEntity> method2();
}
```

In Implementation `method1()` I use `method2()`, But `PostFilter` in `method2()` don't work in this state.

**Why**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation is correct.

To process security annotations, Spring uses *proxies*. A proxy is a dynamically generated class that is put between the caller and the actual implementation. So when you use interface A you are not actually invoking your implementation directly, but a security layer.

By default Spring uses *interface proxies*; the proxy *implements* the interface in question. That means the the security is only invoked when you use A *as an interface*. The security is not enforced when a method is invoked from the implementation class itself, because the implementation does not know of the proxy.

By using *class proxies*, the security annotations can work when a method is invoked from the class itself, because then the proxy *extends* the implementation. However, still only annotations on public methods work.

For a more in-depth explanation of proxies, see [Proxying mechanisms](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-proxying) in Spring framework manual.